# I don't understand what the meaning of 'steps' in evaluate_generator method (keras) is

Tags: python, keras

After I trained a model. Then I feel confused in step of evaluation. It showed variety results.
At first, my train dataset and test dataset are from:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
# create a data generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)
# load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(100, 100), color_mode="rgb",  class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64, subset='training')
# load and iterate test datas
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(100, 100), color_mode="rgb", class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64)
```

**Evaluation:**

```
# evaluate model
loss = model.evaluate_generator(test_it, steps=24)
print('Accuracy: %.2f%%' % (loss[1]*100))
```

Accuracy: 92.90%

```
# evaluate model
loss = model.evaluate_generator(test_it, steps=64)
print('Accuracy: %.2f%%' % (loss[1]*100))
'''
```

Accuracy: 93.43%

```
batch_size= 100
# evaluate model
loss = model.evaluate_generator(test_it, steps= test_it.samples // batch_size)
print('Accuracy: %.2f%%' % (loss[1]*100))
```

Accuracy: 93.28%

It showed variety results if I changed the 'steps='. What is the meaning of this 'steps'? And how do I choose the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/), it says:

> steps: Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from
>   generator before stopping. Optional for Sequence: if unspecified, will
>   use the len(generator) as a number of steps.

Your test generator, as every generator, generates a new batch of data each time you call next. In your case, since `batch_size` is 64, one step corresponds to 64 test examples. But your test dataset has probably more than that. `Keras` provides this functionality so that you can choose to test on a subset of your test data, or if your test data is very big and might not fit in memory (so you predict little by little).

The reason why you see slightly different results when you choose a different step value is because you don't evaluate your model on the same test data

- On the first, you get 24 batches in your test generator --> 24*64 test examples.
- On the second, you get 64*64 test examples.
- On the last one, you take everything (or almost in case the number of test samples is not a multiple of the batch_size).

Comment: Thank you, @Nakor. It's a very clearly answer. So if I want to evaluate **everything** in _my test set_, I just do the last one and set  `steps= test_it.samples // 64` since my test set defined as batch_size=64? And it's not a good idea if my testset is very big?

Comment: It's usually fine to do everything at once (that's what I do most of the time). In general, your test set can fit in memory. Regarding the number of steps to get your whole dataset, it should be fine if you let the argument blank (default is generator length)